# Cygwin Sed - One expression to match string at beginning and not match at end

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, cygwin

I have been trying to find a sed script compatible with cygwin's sed that will match lines with

`^<Transaction>` and without `</Transaction>$`

I need it in one expression. When the lines are matched I need to delete the line ending or append the next line to the end of the current line.

The problem is that we have xml that gets dumped and when the lines are two long it splits it into 2 lines.

Comment: Darn, it removed what I put in quotes,

<Transaction> at the front but not </Transaction> at the end.

Comment: if you meant `regex`, there is **NO** line only has `^` but without `$` .....

Comment: It's unlikely that the files contain literal `^` and `$` -- are you sure?

Comment: I want to match lines that start with <Transaction> but do not have </Transaction> at the end.

I added the ^ and $ to show start and end of line.

Comment: Use a XML parser, please.

Comment: I need to do this with sed, we need to remove the line endings, all I want is to reconstruct an xml line that has been split into two.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formatting (_pretty printing?_) an XML file.

Comment: How is it off topic? I have two consecutive lines that need to be made into one line.

It only needs to do this if the line starts with <Transaction> but does NOT end with </Transaction>.

Oracle splits lines past a certain length when outputting to a text file, aka it inserts a line feed....

Comment: @user3211352 It is off-topic because (1) you seem to be attempting to parse XML using regex, (2) your question is terribly written, (3) you don't have any clue how to ask a question.

Comment: I'm not parsing XML, I'd be parsing XML if I want to find the value between tags <Transaction>"........... I am not I am doing a line by line replacement, what sed is for.......... Read before you spout off dumb suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To use sed:

```
sed '/^<Transaction>/{/<\/Transaction>$/!{N;s/\n/ /}}'
```

This works as follows. For lines beginning with `<Transaction>` but *not* ending with `</Transaction>`, append the next line, and replace the line break with a space. All other lines are left unchanged.

If the added space is unwanted, just change `/ /` to `//`. If any lines of the original file have been split in *three*, run the command twice.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 'chomp if /^<Transaction>/ and not /<\/Transaction>$/' file
```

Comment: I dont understand why this wouldn't work. It's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':0 /<\/Transaction>$/!N;s/\(^<Transaction>.*\)\n/\1/;t0'
```

Search for the line that doesn't end with `</Transaction>`, append the next line (`\n` is still there), check if this combined line starts with `<Transaction>`, if yes -- delete `\n` (`\1` is a backreference to the first group that consists of the pattern in `\(\)`), otherwise do nothing; repeat if `\n` is deleted.

Works on test XML file:

```
<NotATransaction>a</NotATransaction>
<NotATransaction>b1
b2</NotATransaction>
<Transaction>A</Transaction>
<Transaction>B1
B2
B3
B4
B5</Transaction>
<Transaction>C1
C2</Transaction>
<Transaction>D</Transaction>
```

Comment: This works, but one problem, it is matching lines that do not begin and do not end with Transaction, lines such as:


</POSLog>

Comment: @user3211352 does it work for this test file in our environment?

Comment: Works for you test copied and pasted in, not my file.

Comment: @user3211352 updated for case if Transaction element is splitted into several lines. If this also doesn't work, it seems that your file has a different structure that wasn't described in the question.

Comment: Could it be somethign with my line endings? This makes no sense.

Comment: @user3211352 if you upload a sample file and provide a link here, it might help to solve the problem. one of the possible reasons is that there are trailing spaces around elements so these `^...` and `...$` regexp do not match to them.

Comment: Could you repost the original that worked for me but also worked for me?

Comment: @user3211352 you can find it in revisions (click on _edited..._ link). just in case, it's `sed '/<\/Transaction>$/!N;s/\n//'`